# Django: how to create an instance of the model based on the data from the json file?

Tags: json, django

In the project there is a model with existing instances in the database.

```
class Instagram(models.Model):
    userid = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    avatar = models.URLField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    .....
    .....
```

There is another model, so far without instaces

```
class InstagramDemographicsAnalitics(models.Model):
    instagram = models.ForeignKey(Instagram, related_name='demographics')
    age_group = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='female')
    viewer_percentage = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
```

It is necessary from the file statistic.json, which is in the same folder with the project, to take the data for the corresponding **userid** and on their basis create the instances of the model InstagramDemographicsAnalitics.

I have no idea how to do this. I really need advice with a sequence of actions and if possible code example.

Comment: Can you show some *sample* `JSON` object(s)?

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem, you mean data examle from example.json ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an example, this function would take an instance of `Instagram` and return an instance of `InstagramDemographicsAnalitics`:

```
def get_ida_instance(instagram):
    # Load all users from JSON file
    all_users = json.load('example.json')

    # Find the one user, this depends on the format of your JSON file
    my_user = [x for x in all_users if x['userid'] == instagram.userid][0]

    # Map the JSON fields to your Model
    ida = InstagramDemographicsAnalitics()
    ida.instagram = instagram
    ida.age_group = my_user['age_group']
    ida.gender = my_user['gender']
    ida.viewer_percentage = float(str(my_user['viewer_percentage']))
    ida.save()  # If you want to persist it to the database

    # Return the instance
    return ida
```

It depends of course on the actual format of your JSON file.